# How to pass Data from Gridview Item to Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Gridview in my App...
The Gridview shows all the available files in a particular folder, lets say 'Sample Folder'...

What I am trying is to pass the ACTION_VIEW Intent on item click but I am not able to set its Data and Type...
Most of the files are either image or videos...

Here's the code for Activity -

```
public class Downloaded extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declare variables
    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    private String[] FileNameStrings;
    private File[] listFile;
    GridView grid;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    File file;
   TextView empty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        // Check for SD Card
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(Downloaded.this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Sample");

            file.mkdirs();
        }

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
            // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
            FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                // Get the name image file
                FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
            }
        }


        // Locate the GridView in gridview_main.xml
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

       empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);

       empty.setText("You haven't saved any Pic yet...!");

       grid.setEmptyView(empty);

        // Pass String arrays to LazyAdapter Class
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(Downloaded.this, FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);

        // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);



        // Capture gridview item click
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

  //Don't Know what to Do Here :(

                File n = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Sample/" + FileNameStrings);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(n), "*/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an App"));

            }

        });

    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:

onBackPressed();
break;
}
return true;
}

}
```

And here's the Adapter -

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare variables
    private Activity activity;
    String[] filepath;
     String[] filename;

    Context mContext;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewAdapter( Context c ) {
        mContext = c ;
    }

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
        activity = a;
        this.filepath = fpath;
        filename = fname;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.filepath.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);

        // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
        ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);


        // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
        TextView txt = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);

        // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position


        // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
        Glide.with(activity)
        .load(filepath[position])
        .into(img);

       txt.setText(filename[position]);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        // No need to set both Type & Data. if you set one itself enough

        File n = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Sample/" + FileNameStrings);

        i.setType(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(n.getAbsolutePath()));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an App"));
```

**Updated**

Try this for open file

```
MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExt(file).substring(1));
newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimeType);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
try {
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private String fileExt(String url) {
    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
    }
    if (url.lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ext.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0, ext.indexOf("%"));
        }
        if (ext.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            ext = ext.substring(0, ext.indexOf("/"));
        }
        return ext.toLowerCase();

    }
}
```

Comment: Any help on how to send the File Path coz I am not sure If I am doin it the right way... :) it won't show any app

Comment: actually u misunderstood my question... I needed help for setting the Intent data... that    File n = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "Sample/" + FileNameStrings); 
 looks wrong to me.. it doesn't return the File Name :(

Comment: @DarShan it's very simple onItemClickListener use like this
`File n = listFile[position];`